# how can fix data not showing with angularjs and laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Is anyone help me, when I start to code to show data in blade with angularJS, data not showing in the page, even the data exists in the console. This following code in my app.js

// app.js

```
$scope.view_tab = 'shop1';
$scope.changeTab = function(tab) {
    $scope.view_tab = tab;
}

// List product
$scope.loadProduct = function () {
    $http.get('/getproduct').then(function success(e) {
        console.log(e.data);
        $scope.products = e.data.product;
        $scope.totalProduct = $scope.products.length;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.pageSize = 9;
        $scope.sortKey = 'id_kain';
};
```

//index.blade.php

```
<div class="shop-top-bar">
    <div class="shop-tab nav">
        <a ng-class="{'active': view_tab == 'shop1'}" ng-click="changeTab('shop1')" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-table"></i>
        </a>
        <a ng-class="{'active': view_tab == 'shop2'}" ng-click="changeTab('shop2')" data-toggle="tab">
            <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="shop-bottom-area mt-35">
    <div class="tab-content jump">
        <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: view_tab == 'shop1'}">
            <div class="row">
                <div ng-repeat="data in filtered = ( products | filter:search ) | orderBy:sortData | itemsPerPage: 9" class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="product-wrap mb-25 scroll-zoom">
                        <div class="product-img">
                            <a ng-click="showForm(data)">
                                <img class="default-img" ng-src="@{{ data.gambar_kain[0].gambar_kain }}" alt="">
                                <img class="hover-img" ng-src="@{{ data.gambar_kain[1].gambar_kain }}" alt="">
                            </a>

                        </div>
                        <div class="product-content text-center">
                            <h3><a href="">@{{data.nama_kain}}</a></h3>
                            <div class="product-price">
                                <span>@{{numberingFormat(data.data_kain[0].harga_kain)}}</span>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: view_tab == 'shop2'}">
            <div dir-paginate="datas in filtered = ( products | filter:search ) | orderBy:sortData | itemsPerPage:9" class="shop-list-wrap mb-30">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="product-wrap">
                            <div class="product-img">
                                <a ng-click="showForm(datas)">
                                    <img class="default-img" ng-src="@{{ datas.gambar_kain[0].gambar_kain }}" alt="">
                                    <img class="hover-img" ng-src="@{{ datas.gambar_kain[1].gambar_kain }}" alt="">

                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="shop-list-content">
                            <h3><a href="#">@{{data.nama_kain}}</a></h3>
                            <div class="product-list-price">
                                <span>@{{numberingFormat(datas.data_kain[0].harga_kain)}}</span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pro-pagination-style text-center mt-30">
        <dir-pagination-controls
            max-size="1"
            direction-links="true"
            boundary-links="true" >
        </dir-pagination-controls>
    </div>
</div>
```

Data still not shows in the page, there are not errors in this page, but I don't know how can I fix this.

Comment: I think you forgot to use ng-model and your scope don't match

Comment: @Nasser where should I put the ng-model? because that's just show data in dir-paginate

Comment: Debugging code is one of the most important things that a developer can do. When a program’s result is unexpected, debugging is a way for a developer to quickly isolate and identify the problem. In the vast majority of cases, once the problem is identified, the solution is clear. But when a developer does not debug their code, the problem becomes much harder to fix.

Comment: @georgeawg so the answer is? you only give advice that I don't need right now

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is two way to show data in Angular JS when you define the scopes then you need the **ng-bind** or **ng-model** to show data in the front end.

1- AngularJS Data Binding
live Example https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G2DQQ2GSJ3EO

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p ng-bind="firstname "></p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "John will be change";   
});
</script>
```

2-AngularJS ng-model Directive
Live Example https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G2DQQEUEPSOC

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Name: <input ng-model="name">
<h1>You entered: {{name}}</h1>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "John Doe";
});
</script>
```

**NOTE: try with static data and then check that you have valid data to make it dynamic**

I hope this helps you!

Comment: did you attend to answers?